# langchain conversation completes both human and AI conversation [sometimes]

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

It happens sometimes, and it happens only with langchain so far. here are few things that can be the problem.

```
    prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(
    template= role + '''\
    \n
    Current conversation:
    {history}
    Human: {input}
    AI:\
    ''')
```

model:

```
msgs = StreamlitChatMessageHistory(key="langchain_messages")
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(chat_memory=msgs)


llm_chain = LLMChain(
    llm=ChatOpenAI(
        openai_api_key=openai_api_key, 
        temperature=temperature,
        model=model,
        ), 
    prompt=prompt, 
    memory=memory)
```

temp is usually `0.25` and model is `gpt-3.5-turbo-16k`

- I tried changing the order of the prompt
- i set the temp to 0 or 1 and sometimes it doesnt happen at all
- I will not change the model because i know it works

Comment: could you please elaborate more what is the issue

Comment: sure i will try. the way langchain sends prompt to openAI by sending everything, so the prompt+history. so some reason and after chatting for a while, it sends back both side of the conversation, so it starts to predict both AI and Human convo. i am not sure how to stop it. i added an instrcution not to do so, but it is still doing it. my token size is around 1600 and my limit is 16,000. so i dont think this is the issue.

if you have an specific question, please ask